# Cómo se obtiene el campo seleccionado en un select en angular 13

Tags: angular, api, formularios, select

Estoy llamando datos desde una api para hacer un formulario, pero al momento de seleccionar el dato que quiero enviar en un select se envía un array vacío
[image: array vacío]

A continuación el código del formulario

```
<form #usuarioForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addHora(usuarioForm)"
                                                    class="row g-3 mb-3 ">
                                                    <div class="col-12">
                                                        <label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label">Hora</label>
                                                        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"  >
                                                                <option selected  >Open this select menu</option>
                                                                <option *ngFor="let horarios of horariosService.horarios | ObjToArray" value="horarios._id" >{{horarios.horaInicio}} - {{horarios.horaTermino}}</option>
                                                                
                                                                  </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-12">
                                                        <label for="inputOcupacion" class="form-label">Doctor</label>
                                                            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"  >
                                                                <option selected  >Open this select menu</option>
                                                                <option *ngFor="let users of usuariosService.users | ObjToArray" value="{{users._id}}" >{{users.nameUser}}</option>
                                                                
                                                                  </select>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="text-center">

                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger text-uppercase"
                                                            value="Guardar">Agregar
                                                            Hora</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
```

[image: componente]
aquí el componente que utilizo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por mi parte conozco dos maneras de recuperar los datos de un select en angular13

**FormControls** y **NgModels**

Para **FormControls**
Tenes que crear en un FormGroup con dos FormControls

```
public usuarioForm: FormGroup;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.usuarioForm = new FormGroup({
      doctor: new FormControl(''),
      hora: new FormControl('')
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-12" [formGroup]="usuarioForm">
    <label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label">Hora</label>
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" formControlName="hora">
        <option selected  [ngValue]="''">Open this select menu</option>
        <option [ngValue]="horarios._id" *ngFor="let horarios of horariosService.horarios | ObjToArray"  >{{horarios.horaInicio}} - {{horarios.horaTermino}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**NgModels**

```
public class UsuarioModelo {
 hora: string;
 doctor: string;
}
public usuarioModelo: UsuarioModelo;
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-12" >
    <label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label">Hora</label>
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" [(ngModel)]="usuarioModelo.hora">
            <option selected  [ngValue]="''">Open this select menu</option>
            <option [ngValue]="horarios._id" *ngFor="let horarios of horariosService.horarios | ObjToArray"  >{{horarios.horaInicio}} - {{horarios.horaTermino}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Gracias
ngModel era la solucion c: